# JSON Extract with IN statement, possible?

Tags: php, mysql, json

This query works as expected.

```
SELECT DISTINCT JSON_UNQUOTE(JSON_EXTRACT(`colors` , '$."65"')) FROM color
```

Is it possible to do the same query but with an SQL IN statement as I'm trying to do below.

```
SELECT DISTINCT JSON_UNQUOTE(JSON_EXTRACT(`colors` , IN('$."65"','$."66"','$."67"','$."68"','$."69"'))) FROM color
```

I also want the result ordered by value ASC.

Answer (score 0):

In 5.7 JSON_EXTRACT can accept more than 1 path element. Will this help to solve your problem?

```
SELECT DISTINCT JSON_UNQUOTE(JSON_EXTRACT(`colors` ,
 '$."65"',
 '$."66"',
 '$."67"',
 '$."68"',
 '$."69"')) 
FROM color;
```