# Is it possible to do JSON_EXTRACT with multiple keys?

Tags: php, mysql, json

First of all, I am not sure if my title explains this question in the correct way but I think my code will.

Instead of doing this:

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE JSON_EXTRACT(`cars`,'$."65"') = 'Toyota' OR JSON_EXTRACT(`cars `,'$."66"') = 'Toyota' OR JSON_EXTRACT(`cars `,'$."67"') = 'Toyota'
```

I want to do this:

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE JSON_EXTRACT(`cars`,any of these 65,66,67) = 'Toyota'
```

Can this be done?

Comment: Provide table structure and example data.. Place it on http://www.sqlfiddle.com.. Then we can help you.

Comment: `JSON_EXTRACT(json_doc, path[, path] ...)` source https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-search-functions.html#function_json-extract .. Looks like it's possible to include multiple paths..

Answer (score 6):

According to the [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-search-functions.html), you may pass any number of paths as arguments 2 onward to the `JSON_EXTRACT` function.  So the following should work:

```
SELECT *
FROM yourTable
WHERE JSON_UNQUOTE(JSON_EXTRACT(`cars`, '$."65"', '$."66"', '$."67"')) LIKE '%"Toyota"%';
```

### Demo

Note that the `WHERE` clause will actually return string values in the form `["some_value"]`, hence I compare against this.  Someone with more experience with MySQL's JSON API can probably do better than what I wrote above.  But, this does at least partially answer your question; yes, you can extract multiple paths in a single call to `JSON_EXTRACT`.

Comment: Slightly wondering why OP needs to be told again today though ... https://stackoverflow.com/q/50528364/1427878

Comment: @CBroe I'm part of the problem; I haven't tested this yet...I'm setting up a query now.

Comment: This question is little bit different.. Because JSON_EXTRACT() with multiple paths returns a JSON ARRAY..Guess he should not figure it out on how to match that with the string Toyota @CBroe ... TimBiegeleisen answer looks like it's solving that problem

Comment: "Someone with more experience with MySQL's JSON API can probably do better than what I wrote above" MySQL JSON API is a bit bit i would expect `JSON_UNQUOTE(JSON_EXTRACT(`cars`, '$."65"', '$."66"', '$."67"')) = JSON_ARRAY("Toyota")` would also select http://rextester.com/UXF29788.. Your query might be the best solution.

Comment: Tim, your solution is pretty close to what I want. The only thing I don't want is the LIKE at the end. I tried to use = instead but that gives me no rows.

Comment: @PeterKarlsson Well the thing is, if you check the demo, each row might return something like `["Toyota", "Bentley", "Ford"]`, so `LIKE` is the only way I can see to assert what you want.

Comment: The real issue is you want to search multiple paths in one go.  This means that what you get back might be an array, consisting of multiple values.

Comment: Ok I understand. Time to rethink what I'm doing. Thanks Tim.

Comment: @PeterKarlsson Another approach you may want to consider is to just store all your JSON data as plain text, and handle it completely in your app layer.